# How to create Tabbed Html page using JSP

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I want to create tabbed Html page which will having multiple submit buttons on each Tab.
How to create Tabbed html pages using JSP.

Comment: Tagging for later or another editor: Can this question be edited to remove improve its focus considering the accepted answer doesn't focus on  JSP? Sorry... no time today and merely removing a very old favourite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is something not related to **JSP**. This is about how you present in the **client side**. You can use a lot of jQuery Tab plugins. But just to start, you can use something like the below. Get your JSP generate the HTML structure this way:

**HTML**

```
<div class="tabbable">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tabcontent">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab">
            Tab 1 Contents
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab">
            Tab 2 Contents
        </div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tab">
            Tab 3 Contents
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI';}
.tabbable .tabs {list-style: none; margin: 0 10px; padding: 0;}
.tabbable .tabs li {list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; display: inline-block; position: relative; z-index: 1;}
.tabbable .tabs li a {text-decoration: none; color: #000; border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 5px; display: inline-block; border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0; background: #f5f5f5;}
.tabbable .tabs li a.active, .tabbable .tabs li a:hover {border-bottom-color: #fff; background: #fff;}
.tabcontent {border: 1px solid #ccc; margin-top: -1px; padding: 10px;}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tabbable").find(".tab").hide();
    $(".tabbable").find(".tab").first().show();
    $(".tabbable").find(".tabs li").first().find("a").addClass("active");
    $(".tabbable").find(".tabs").find("a").click(function(){
        tab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".tabbable").find(".tab").hide();
        $(".tabbable").find(".tabs").find("a").removeClass("active");
        $(tab).show();
        $(this).addClass("active");
        return false;
    });
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/LZEHP/