# Changing active navigation tab when referencing from another JSP

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, el, scriptlet

I am writing some front end for a project. Throughout all of my pages I have a navigation bar. Currently, instead of a large block of code filling up the beginning of every JSP/HTML file, I simply reference another file that contains the navigation bar:

```
<%@include file="navbar.jsp" %>
```

I have two questions:

(1) I've heard using scriptlets are bad. How can I replace it with HTML or EL? But more importantly,

(2) Each of the pages have a slight variation, since there will be a class='active' from Bootstrap for the selected page on the navbar. Is there a way to change the referenced file, without actually changing the original file?

Comment: Nobody has answered in 5 days, I'm assuming both aren't possible?

Comment: (1) You should probably use EL instead of a scriptlet, and (2) you shouldn't have to change the file but instead use javascript to handle tabs (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20811206/creating-tabs-in-jsp or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948634/how-to-create-tabbed-html-page-using-jsp)

Comment: What's the EL equivalent of what I have  above?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with JS, could you provide a snippet/elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I found the JSTL tag that does the same thing as the scriptlet above but better:

`<jsp:include page="x.jsp"/>`

This solves my first question, but doesn't solve my second one. I will be using this until another better answer is posted.